# MySQL y Oracle Database en el mismo pc

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

Soy estudiante y tengo Oracle Database instalada en mi pc. Me gustaría usar MySQL para un proyecto personal. ¿Hay algún problema en tener ambas instaladas en la misma máquina?¿hace falta alguna configuración específica?¿el pc puede verse afectado a nivel de rendimiento?

Gracias y saludos,

Comment: no hay ningún problema mas que el uso de RAM y disco.. si tienes suficiente no hay problema. Es algo común hacerlo.

Comment: Con un poco de retraso, pero, gracias!!!